# count values in Mysql 5.5 from one column and group by other column

Tags: mysql

I want to know number of column1 value group by column2 and total count in **mysql 5.5**.
below example will help to understand my problem:

```
-------------------
column1 | column2
-------------------
of      | d1
of      | d1
sf      | d2
sf      | d3
sf      | d3
tf      | d2
tf      | d3
tf      | d1
of      | d1
-------------------
```

the output will be:

```
------------------------------
column2 | of | sf | tf | total
-------------------------------
d1      | 3  | 0  |  1 | 4
d2      | 0  | 1  |  1 | 2
d3      | 0  | 2  |  1 | 3
------------------------------
```

I searched but didn't found exact solution for my scenario.
I can do it with RANK but 5.5 will not support RANK function.

Comment: Your table has no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course

Comment: Are possible values of column1 known prior ? Or do you want something more dynamic ?

Comment: Strawberry, Thanks for you comment, it's just an Example in real table we have all Keys and relations and indexing in place.

Comment: Good question Thomas, right now the values are known but it change in future, so looking for a dynamic query. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select column2,
  sum(column1 = 'of') of,
  sum(column1 = 'sf') sf,
  sum(column1 = 'tf') tf,
  count(*) total
from tablename
group by column2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/adTMQT2Po2krZnudR75tQA/0).
Results:

```
| column2 | of  | sf  | tf  | total |
| ------- | --- | --- | --- | ----- |
| d1      | 3   | 0   | 1   | 4     |
| d2      | 0   | 1   | 1   | 2     |
| d3      | 0   | 2   | 1   | 3     |
```

Comment: Thank you forpas, can we get some  generic solution, what if we have more values in column1.